# How to add exception in the oracle statement

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have the following code

```
CREATE PROCEDURE get_details (
  start_time IN  DATE,
  End_Time   IN  DATE,
  o_results1 OUT SYS_REFCURSOR,
  o_results2 OUT SYS_REFCURSOR,
  o_results3 OUT SYS_REFCURSOR,
  o_results4 OUT SYS_REFCURSOR,
  o_results5 OUT SYS_REFCURSOR,
  o_results6 OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
)
AS

BEGIN

  OPEN o_results1 FOR
  SELECT DESCRIPTION, ACTION_BY FROM table1 WHERE  date_time BETWEEN start_time AND End_Time;

  EXCEPTION
   WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN 
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('NO DATA EXISTS IN TABLE1');  

  OPEN o_results2 FOR
  SELECT *
  FROM   table2
  WHERE  date_time BETWEEN start_time AND End_Time;

  OPEN o_results3 FOR
  SELECT *
  FROM   table3
  WHERE  date_time BETWEEN start_time AND End_Time;

  OPEN o_results4 FOR
  SELECT *
  FROM   table4
  WHERE  date_time BETWEEN start_time AND End_Time;

  OPEN o_results5 FOR
  SELECT *
  FROM   table5
  WHERE  date_time BETWEEN start_time AND End_Time;

  OPEN o_results6 FOR
  SELECT *
  FROM   table6
  WHERE  date_time BETWEEN start_time AND End_Time;
END;
/
```

What I want is to give an output that there is no data in table1, when I query the following

```
VARIABLE o_result1 REFCURSOR; 
VARIABLE o_result2 REFCURSOR; 
VARIABLE o_result3 REFCURSOR; 
VARIABLE o_result4 REFCURSOR; 
VARIABLE o_result5 REFCURSOR; 
VARIABLE o_result6 REFCURSOR;

EXECUTE get_details( TO_DATE('16-Jul-2015 04:00:10', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), TO_DATE('16-Jul-2015 20:14:16', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), :o_result1, :o_result2, :o_result3, :o_result4, :o_result5, :o_result6 ); 

PRINT o_result1;
```

Here, date_time is the column that stores the date and the time. 
I am getting an error though. Why is that? Please note that I am new to oracle procedure writing.

Error:

```
ORA-24338: statement handle not executed 24338. 00000 - "statement handle not executed" 
*Cause: A fetch or describe was attempted before executing a statement handle.     
*Action: Execute a statement and then fetch or describe the data.
```

Comment: Can u post the error you r getting?

Comment: `ORA-24338: statement handle not executed
24338. 00000 -  "statement handle not executed"
*Cause:    A fetch or describe was attempted before executing a
           statement handle.
*Action:   Execute a statement and then fetch or describe the data.`

Comment: The whole thing works perfectly just by removing the exception statement.

Answer (score 0):

use begin .. end within begin.. end like below

```
BEGIN 
BEGIN
<query>
<exception>
END;

<query>
<exception>


END;
/
```

take help from [When should I nest PL/SQL BEGIN...END blocks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2334659/when-should-i-nest-pl-sql-begin-end-blocks)