# How to handle exceptions in for loop for insert rows using a stored procedure? Oracle PLSQL

Tags: oracle, for-loop, stored-procedures, plsql

I'm coding a complex PLSQL block (complex for me hahaha) to insert rows using information from the FOR  LOOP CURSOR and add parameters to insert using a stored procedure. The current problem is there are around 200 rows to be inserted but when a simple row fail to insert all rows inserted broke and oracle execute a ROLLBACK command (I think so). So... How could I handle exceptions to insert succefully all rounds I can and when any rows fail show it in screen? Thanks

```
FOR i IN c_mig_saldos LOOP
        IF i.tipo_comprobante = 'P' THEN -- Nota de debito (positivo)
            v_cmp_p.prn_codigo := 'VIV';
            v_cmp_p.tcm_codigo := 'NRA';
            v_cmp_p.cmp_fecha_emision := TRUNC(SYSDATE);
            v_cmp_p.cmp_fecha_contable := TRUNC(SYSDATE);
            v_cmp_p.cmp_observacion := 'GENERACION AUTOMATICA DE SALDOS';
            v_cmp_p.cli_codigo := i.cli_codigo;

            v_tab_dco_p(1).cnc_codigo := 'VIA';
            v_tab_dco_p(1).dco_precio_unitario := i.total_final;
            v_tab_dco_p(1).dco_cantidad := 1;
            v_tab_dco_p(1).dco_importe := i.total_final;

            -- Insert a new row using stored procedure but when a itereted fail, no rows has inserted in table
            PKG_COMPROBANTES.PRC_INSERTAR_COMPROBANTE(v_cmp_p, v_tab_dco_p, v_tab_pgc_p, v_tab_apl_p, v_tab_mar_p); 
            COMMIT;
        END IF;
END LOOP;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When should I nest PL/SQL BEGIN...END blocks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2334659/when-should-i-nest-pl-sql-begin-end-blocks)

Comment: Yes you can do what you want to accomplish. But no one can guide you properly without knowing why the package call that inserts fails and what you want to do about it. Without understanding, all anyone can do is guide you to ignore the failed inserts which is generally a bad answer.

Comment: Thanks Michael, Stored procedure pass for parameters information for insert a new row in some tables, and return (in index by table) information about the new single row inserted. I want to stored in a table information about rows has not inserted. so in the end of block I want to show information about rows not inserted and later saved in txt (using toad button). Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

```
-- Insert a new row using stored procedure but when a itereted fail, no rows has inserted in table
begin
    PKG_COMPROBANTES.PRC_INSERTAR_COMPROBANTE(v_cmp_p, v_tab_dco_p, v_tab_pgc_p, v_tab_apl_p, v_tab_mar_p);
    exception
        when others then --this could be made more specific but you didn't say what type of error you were getting
            -- Log to a table so you can export failed inserts later.
            -- Make sure log table cols are large enough to store everything that can possibly be inserted here...
            ErrorLogProc(the, cols, you, want, to, see, and, SQLERRM);
end;
```

In the ErrorLogProc() I'd recommend a couple things, here is a snippet of some things I do in my error logging proc that you may find helpful (it's just a few snippets, not intended to fully work, but you should get the idea)...

```
oname varchar2(100);
pname varchar2(100);
lnumb varchar2(100);
callr varchar2(100);
g1B CHAR(2) := chr(13)||chr(10);

PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;  --important!

begin

  owa_util.who_called_me(oname, pname, lnumb, callr);

  --TRIM AND FORMAT FOR ERRORLOG
  lv_errLogText := 'Package: '||pname||' // Version: '||version_in||' // Line Number: '||lnumb||' // Error: ';
  lv_string1    := mid(errStr_in,1,4000-Length(lv_errLogText));
  lv_errLogText := lv_errLogText||lv_string1;
  lv_errLogText := lv_errLogText||g1B||'Error Backtrace: '||replace(dbms_utility.format_error_backtrace,'ORA-', g1b||'ORA-');

  insertIntoYourErrorLogTable(lv_errLogText, and, whatever, else, you, need);

commit;
```

Answer (score 0):

To keep this simple, since there's not enough information to know the what and why of the question, this will kick out some text information about failures as desired.

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
```

Then here's an anonymous PL/SQL block:

```
BEGIN
    FOR i IN c_mig_saldos 
    LOOP
        -- not relevant

        BEGIN
            PKG_COMPROBANTES.PRC_INSERTAR_COMPROBANTE(v_cmp_p, v_tab_dco_p, v_tab_pgc_p, v_tab_apl_p, v_tab_mar_p); 
        EXCEPTION
            -- The goal of this is to ignore but output information about your failures
            WHEN OTHERS THEN DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('whatever you want about v_cmp_p, v_tab_dco_p, v_tab_pgc_p, v_tab_apl_p, v_tab_mar_p or SQLERRM/SQLCODE or the error stack - not enough info in the question');
        END;
    END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Note: I have removed the commit from the execution.
Then if you like what you see...

```
SQL> commit;
```

Ideally, if I knew more about why the insert failures were expected to occur and what I wanted to do about them, I would not insert them in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with comment that more information is needed, but a couple of things to consider:

1. Does this need to be done as a loop - if you can write your query as a select statement, then you can do a simple insert without the need for PLSQL, which would be simpler and likely quicker (set based SQL vs row-by-row PLSQL)
2. You say a `ROLLBACK` is occuring - you have a commit inside your `IF` statement, so any records which make it into your `IF` statement and succesfully make it through your insert procedure will be committed i.e. they will not be rolled back; You should consider if some records you think are being rolled back are actually not making it into the `IF` statement at all

Can you provide example data, or an example of the error you are receiving?